# Feedback property of Draggable widget is not showing scroll position

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to achieve a screen similar to Windows Explorer using Flutter. I have draggable screens, but when I drag a screen, the feedback widget appears at the top while the scroll position remains unchanged. I want the widget to be dragged exactly as it appears on the screen, including its scroll position.

Is there a way to maintain the scroll position when dragging a widget in Flutter, so that it doesn't scroll to the top during the drag operation? Any help or guidance on how to achieve this behavior would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried various keys and scroll controller, including PageStorageKey, to save the position after a drag operation, but I'm still encountering issues while dragging.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Observer(
      builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          left: store.position.dx,
          top: store.position.dy,
          child: Draggable(
            child: widget.isIcon ?  OnClick() : widget.child,
           ignoringFeedbackSemantics: false,
            feedback: widget.child,
            childWhenDragging: Container(),
            onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
              setState(() {
                print(velocity.toString());
                if (velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx == 0.0 &&
                    velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy == 0.0) return;
                store.position = Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy );
              });
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: is this what you looking for? 

onDragEnd: (details) {
            print(details.offset);
            setState(() {
              store.position = details.offset;
            });
          }